# Работа с onLongClick(RecyclerView)

Tags: android

Есть метод который удаляет элемент при долгом нажатии на него:

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        files.remove(files.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
```

Вопрос, как мне сделать чтобы вместо удаления в начале было подтверждение в ActionBar? Чтобы появлялось 2 кнопки "удалить" и "отмена"?

Мне писать новое меню для ActionBar и заменять его при долгом нажатии и затем в зависимости от нажатой кнопки возвращать то меню которое было до это?

Просто кажется эта реализация какая-то "кривая"...может есть стандартные средства которые позволяют реализовать такой функционал?

Comment: Придется именно так - я лично другого варианта не знаю. Было бы крайне любопытно, если есть другие варианты конфирмации...

Я правда делаю немного не так: вешаю `DialogFragment` с вопросиком и не заморачиваюсь на экшн бар

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно делать новое меню. Для таких случаев есть ActionMode -  альтернатива контекстному меню, отображается как новое меню в ActionBar. Вот небольшая [статья](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/183-urok-113-android-3-actionmode-kak-alternativa-kontekstnomu-menju.html) по нему

Comment: Во, именно то что и искал, благодарю:)